# Enable Pulsaudio devices via network: Why can't I see the devices?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have set up pulseaudio on my Ubuntu devices as well as raspbian. I tried to share the devices over the network via `paprefs`. To make the checkboxes visible in the pulseaudio settings, I had to use

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/lib/pulse-16.1+dfsg1 /usr/lib/pulse-16.1
```

to create the link.
Now the checkboxes are there, but I don't see any devices over the network. I can ping them in the local network, connect via ssh, but I don't see any network audio devices in the settings or `pavucontrol`.
These instructions did not help either:
https://gist.github.com/xarinatan/c415341ff34eab445cfb073988dcf6c1
What is the problem? What can I do to find out where the problem lies? I remember doing this 4 years ago and it worked with just a few clicks.

Comment: With help of the german ubuntuusers forum i could solve it: https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/sound-uebers-netzwerk-2/1/

Answer (score 0):

The [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#Sharing_audio_devices_with_computers_on_the_network)  describes how to do this with the current Ubuntu Pipewire pulseaudio programs.

These commands helped me to solve my problem:

```
pactl load-module module-native-protocol-tcp listen=192.168.10.81 #host ip
pactl load-module module-zeroconf-publish   #make speaker available to network
pactl load-module module-loopback           #loop back microphone input to speaker output
pactl load-module module-zeroconf-discover  #search for available speaker in the network
pactl load-module module-combine-sink       #output to all sinks available
```

[Thanks to the German Ubuntuusers forum](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/sound-uebers-netzwerk-2/1/)